# Subquery in CTE

Tags: sql-server

i'm trying to get the status of student after the semester ends
and then update the status in it's table 
can i use subquery inside the CTE ??

```
;with temp As
(
    select CASE WHEN Status = 0 then 'Passed'
                when status >0 and status < 2 then 'uncomplete'
                else 'Failed' end Studentstatus
    from
    (
    SELECT     StudentID, 
               sum(CASE WHEN CourseStatus =1 then 1 else 0 end) Status
    FROM         StudentFinalResultsDetails
    group by StudentID
    )As t
)--the error in this line
```

the problem is
Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you try using it?

Comment: the problem is Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this, either use a CTE or subquery; you are mixing both of them, just do this:

```
with temp As
(
  SELECT   StudentID, 
           sum(CASE WHEN CourseStatus =1 then 1 else 0 end) Status
  FROM     StudentFinalResultsDetails
  group by StudentID
) -- You have to select something after the brackets 
select CASE WHEN Status = 0 then 'Passed'
                when status >0 and status < 2 then 'uncomplete'
                else 'Failed' end AS Studentstatus
from temp
```

**Or:** remove `WITH CTE`:

```
select CASE WHEN Status = 0 then 'Passed'
            when status >0 and status < 2 then 'uncomplete'
            else 'Failed' end Studentstatus
from
(
   SELECT     StudentID, 
           sum(CASE WHEN CourseStatus =1 then 1 else 0 end) Status
   FROM         StudentFinalResultsDetails
   group by StudentID
)As t
```

---

### Update

The problem in the query in your question, you have to move the part:

```
 select CASE WHEN Status = 0 then 'Passed'
                when status >0 and status < 2 then 'uncomplete'
                else 'Failed' end AS Studentstatus`
```

to the outer of the brackets of the `WITH temp ( .... )` then after it select whatever you want from it.

Because:

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT
>   statement of the view.

In your query, you didn't put any statements after it. See [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: i need to use CTE to Update 'StudentFinalResults' the table that contain  status

Comment: do u know whats the problem with the query i wrote in my  question ??